# Django model save issue

Tags: python, django, model, save

I will clear my situation here.
i have some model as:

```
class Messages(models.Model):
    message_idnr = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    mailbox_idnr = models.ForeignKey(Mailboxes, null=True, db_column='mailbox_idnr', blank=True)
    physmessage = models.ForeignKey(Physmessage, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s'%(self.physmessage)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'messages'


class Mailboxes(models.Model):
    mailbox_idnr = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    owner_idnr = models.ForeignKey(Users, null=True, db_column='owner_idnr', blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    permission = models.SmallIntegerField(default =2)
    seq = models.BigIntegerField(default = 0)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'mailboxes'


class Users(models.Model):
    user_idnr = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    passwd = models.CharField(max_length=130)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s'%(self.userid)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'users'

class Physmessage(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    messagesize = models.BigIntegerField()
    rfcsize = models.BigIntegerField()
    internal_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s'%(self.id)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'physmessage'
```

then, i have one views.py call this function like

```
def dbmail_move_email_to_dir(mailbox,maildir,mailvalue,destination):
    db_user = Users.objects.get(userid = mailbox.email)
    if maildir.lower() == 'inbox':
        db_source_dir = Mailboxes.objects.get(Q(owner_idnr = db_user),Q(name = 'INBOX'))
    else:
        db_source_dir = Mailboxes.objects.get(Q(owner_idnr = db_user),Q(name = 'INBOX.%s'%maildir))
    db_des_dir = Mailboxes.objects.get(Q(owner_idnr = db_user),Q(name = 'INBOX.%s'%destination))
    for value in mailvalue:
        print 'physical value of email %s'%value
        print 'from maildir id %s'%db_source_dir.mailbox_idnr
        print 'to maildir id %s'%db_des_dir.mailbox_idnr
        print Physmessage.objects.get(id = value)
        print len(Messages.objects.filter(physmessage = Physmessage.objects.get(id = value)))
        for row in Messages.objects.filter(physmessage = Physmessage.objects.get(id = value)):
            print 'delete each row %s'%row
            print 'current mailbox %s'%row.mailbox_idnr.mailbox_idnr
            row.mailbox_idnr=db_des_dir
            print 'current mailbox %s'%row.mailbox_idnr.mailbox_idnr
            row.save()
            print 'current mailbox %s'%row.mailbox_idnr.mailbox_idnr

    return True
```

when i run this function from test file i get result like

```
physical value of email 15
from maildir id 128
to maildir id 126
15
1
delete each row 15
current mailbox 128
current mailbox 126
current mailbox 126
```

it will change mailbox_idnr to new value and i see it in postgres database. But when i call this function in views, login print is the same, but mailbox_idnr not change.

```
physical value of email 46
from maildir id 125
to maildir id 128
46
1
delete each row 46
current mailbox 125
current mailbox 128
current mailbox 128
```

hope every one can suggest to fix it. I have login admin and can change it too. but in my View, i cant change it. Cant delete it too.

Thanks,

Comment: Please add your MyModel definition and the output you are seeing. It will help in understanding the situation.

Comment: How do you check that "the data in the database is not changed" ?